# Can't calibrate controller

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, windows-10

I bought a Wii U Pro controller + a Mayflash adapter in order to connect it as a 360 controller in Windows 10. The problem is that the calibration is off. When I calibrate it it looks fine at first but it doesn't make a difference when testing it. Plese see the video I made: